# Laravel mysql special query

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table called: roast_coffees
In it I have the fields:
id
coffee_id
weight
packed

I need to find the oldest record where the coffee_id equals X and weight field minus the packed field is bigger than Zero.

I am doing it like this:

```
$result = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT id, weight, packed FROM roast_coffees WHERE coffee_id = 3 AND weight - packed > 0"));
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a better way to do this?
2. How do I get only the latest record that fits the query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by the created_at date and then limit your results to 1.  This would find the oldest record.

Eg

```
$result = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT id, weight, packed FROM roast_coffees WHERE coffee_id = 3 AND weight - packed > 0 ORDER BY created_at ASC LIMIT 0, 1"));
```

As for a better way, you have tagged this question with `laravel-eloquent`, however you are using a raw DB query.  Have you set up your models so that you can use eloquent queries?